# Event onclick doesn't happen NextJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js

index.js:

```js
function Home () {
    return <div>
        <html>
       
 <head>
<title>Site</title> 
</head>


<body>
 
 
 <div class= 'v5_3' onclick = "func_click()"></div> 


 </body>
    
        </html>
        
        </div>
    
    }
    
function func_click() {
   
   
    alert('ALERT!!');


        }
        export default Home ; func_click
```

I'm developing locally with nextjs through the `npm run dev` that I learned [through this link
(19:00 ate 21:50)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EW7m2WIvFgQ) however when I click on the button that is inside the div 'v5_3' which in turn is in the main.css file:

```
.v5_3 {  
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(5, 5, 5);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 1171px;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  
  
}
```

,that is being imported by the _app.js file
:

```
import './main.css'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
  }
```

Which in turn are all in the pages folder:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

does not execute my alert, which is in function
`func_click()`:

```
function func_click() {
  alert(' ALERT!!');


        }
```

I'm not able to do this interaction with JavaScript, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you know that Next.js is a React.js framework. This means that you need to handle clicks the way React handles them.

Start by defining the function inside the component. This is not mandatory but adds cohesion to your code.
Then reference to the function by using `onClick` camelcased and the bracket syntax `onClick={funcClick}` to bind the click function to the div.

For the `class` use `className` instead. These elements are not (yet) HTML elements and should be seen as object.  With that in mind `className` is a property of an `HTMLElement` object.

```
function Home() {

  const funcClick = () => {
    alert("ALERT!!");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Site</title>
        </head>

        <body>
          <div className="v5_3" onClick={funcClick}></div>
        </body>
      </html>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue, but succeeded resolve this.
The cause was z-index. You should check your css properties.